# CaptureScreen in Objective-C using OpenGL on an IMac

Tags: objective-c, opengl

I have a multidisplay system, 27 inch (2560 x 1440) and Apple Cinema Display (1920 x 1200) with ATI Radeon HD 5750 1024 MB graphics card.  I used to be able to capture screen shots with my previous iMac with a Nvidia card, also multidisplay systems.  Now I get an OpenGL error.

> This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys001
>   [Switching to process 28434 thread 0x0] 2011-08-20 19:07:42.040
>   DetectObjectColor[28434:c03] invalid fullscreen drawable 2011-08-20
>   19:07:42.043 DetectObjectColor[28434:c03] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[OpenGLScreenReader readPartialScreenToBuffer:bufferBaseAddress:],
>   /Documents/Personal/DetectObjectColor/OpenGLScreenReader.m:230
>   2011-08-20 19:07:42.043 DetectObjectColor[28434:c03] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'OpenGL error 0x0506'

I call this from my main program:

```
OpenGLScreenReader *mOpenGLScreenReader;
mOpenGLScreenReader = [[OpenGLScreenReader alloc] init];
[mOpenGLScreenReader readRectScreen:CGRectMake(570, 265, 35, 800)];
```

This is my init method

```
-(id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
     // Create a full-screen OpenGL graphics context
     // Specify attributes of the GL graphics context
      NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes[] = {

     NSOpenGLPFANoRecovery,
        NSOpenGLPFAFullScreen,
        NSOpenGLPFAScreenMask,
        CGDisplayIDToOpenGLDisplayMask(kCGDirectMainDisplay),
        (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute) 0
    };

    NSOpenGLPixelFormat *glPixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
    if (!glPixelFormat)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create OpenGL context used to render
    mGLContext = [[[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:glPixelFormat shareContext:nil] autorelease];

    // Cleanup, pixel format object no longer needed
    [glPixelFormat release];
    if (!mGLContext)
    {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }
    [mGLContext retain];

    // Set our context as the current OpenGL context
    [mGLContext makeCurrentContext];

    // Set full-screen mode
    [mGLContext setFullScreen];

    NSRect mainScreenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
    mWidth = mainScreenRect.size.width;
    mHeight = mainScreenRect.size.height;       
    mByteWidth = mWidth * 4;                // Assume 4 bytes/pixel for now
    mByteWidth = (mByteWidth + 3) & ~3;    // Align to 4 bytes      
    mData = malloc(mByteWidth * mHeight);
    NSAssert( mData != 0, @"malloc failed");        
  }
  return self;
}
```

This is my readRectScreen method which is giving me the error on OpenGL when it executes the readPartialScreenToBuffer method

```
- (void) readRectScreen:(CGRect) srcRect
{
    mWidth = srcRect.size.width;
mHeight = srcRect.size.height;
mByteWidth = mWidth * 4;                // Assume 4 bytes/pixel for now
mByteWidth = (mByteWidth + 3) & ~3;    // Align to 4 bytes

mData = malloc(mByteWidth * mHeight);

[self readPartialScreenToBuffer:srcRect bufferBaseAddress: mData];
}

- (void) readPartialScreenToBuffer: (CGRect) srcRect bufferBaseAddress: (void *) baseAddress
{
// select front buffer as our source for pixel data
    GLint width, height;
    width = srcRect.size.width;
    height = srcRect.size.height;
    glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
    //Read OpenGL context pixels directly.
    // For extra safety, save & restore OpenGL states that are changed
    glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4); /* Force 4-byte alignment */
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);

    //Read a block of pixels from the frame buffer
glReadPixels((GLint)srcRect.origin.x, (GLint)srcRect.origin.y, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV,baseAddress);

    glPopClientAttrib();

    //Check for OpenGL errors
    GLenum theError = GL_NO_ERROR;
    theError = glGetError();
    NSAssert1( theError == GL_NO_ERROR, @"OpenGL error 0x%04X", theError);
}
```

Can anybody please help... I am totally lost as to where the error might be.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your new computer has Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) installed. Lion does not allow this method of screen capture (reading the front buffer) anymore. Applications must migrate to CGDisplayCaptureImage() API, which was introduced in 10.6.

Comment: Thanks to both answers.. comments were extremely uselful.  I will look into CGDisplayCaptureImage() API

Comment: I have found the solution in the Apple Developer site, using as you recommended CGDisplayCreateImage                                             GImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImage(kCGDirectMainDisplay);  Full details at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1741/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011008

Answer (score 2):

Your issue seems to be, that you don't get/have a valid OpenGL context. But that's not your real problem:

OpenGL is a drawing/rendering library. *glReadPixels* is meant to read back the image generated by your program. OpenGL *is not a general purpose graphics API* (though some/many people confuse it for that).

For some time one could exploit the side effects between OpenGL contexts, windows and framebuffers to take screenshots using *glReadPixels*. *On modern systems with compositing window managers this no longer works!*

You're barking up the wrong tree, sorry.